# Including other files in c++ for File I/O

Tags: c++, file-io, eclipse-plugin, embedded-resource, mingw32

Is there a way to add files to the final .exe in a c++ program ?
For example, suppose I want to play a sound file. Instead of including the sound file separately with the release .exe, the file should be part of the exe.
Im aware about the use of resource files, in C++. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zabda143%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article on the MSDN website, says that it is possible to use resources in Visual C++. Can I also use them on Eclipse, with MinGW ? Please also explain how to use them.

Comment: The best portable way of doing this would probably be to have one large static byte array in a file. I know you can do this relatively easily for images, but the idea should be the same for other pieces of data.

Comment: How would I 'include' that file in my .exe ? And how would I create a byte array out of the image in the first place ?

Comment: @viraj: Typically by converting the binary file into an array declaration: `char sound_foo_wav[] = { 0,5,-42, ...` and compiling that in. On unixy systems, `xxd -i` can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

Actually, the easiest way is to simply append the binary contents to the end of the .exe.  Append a 4-byte "length" value after that.  It will *not* affect your ability to run the .exe.  Then, at runtime:

1) Open your .exe as a binary file, read-only.

2) fseek (or equivalent) to .exe size - 4.

3) read the length

4) fseek to exe size - length - 4

5) read the binary file

This works for DOS, Windows and Linux files.

Comment: And how exactly do you convert an image (such as a bitmap or jpeg) to a binary file ?
Edit:
If I open an image using notepad, am I looking at it's binary file ?

Comment: An image IS a binary file. So's a text file, for that matter. If you open an image in Notepad, you see which characters you get when you interpret the data as text.